# Redis error when deploying to DigitalOcean using Capistrano

Tags: redis, ruby-on-rails-5, capistrano, digital-ocean

I want to deploy my app in to my digitalOcean server using Capistrano, but everytime I want to deploy an Ugly error from Redis Pops Out:

```
  INFO [a9e1ab5b] Running RBENV_ROOT=$HOME/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.5.3 $HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec sidekiq --index 0 --pidfile /home/deplo
y/app_backend/shared/tmp/pids/sidekiq-0.pid --environment dev --logfile /home/deploy/app_backend/shared/log/sidekiq.log --config /home/depl
oy/app_backend/current/config/sidekiq.yml --daemon as deploy@[server_ip]
 DEBUG [a9e1ab5b] Command: cd /home/deploy/app_backend/current && ( export RBENV_ROOT="$HOME/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.5.3" ; RBENV_ROOT=$HOME/.r
benv RBENV_VERSION=2.5.3 $HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec sidekiq --index 0 --pidfile /home/deploy/app_backend/shared/tmp/pids/sidekiq-0.
pid --environment dev --logfile /home/deploy/app_backend/shared/log/sidekiq.log --config /home/deploy/app_backend/current/config/sidekiq.ym
l --daemon )
 DEBUG [a9e1ab5b]       invalid option: --index
 DEBUG [a9e1ab5b]       /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sidekiq-6.0.7/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb:291:in `parse_options'
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sidekiq-6.0.7/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb:205:in `setup_options'
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sidekiq-6.0.7/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb:24:in `parse'
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sidekiq-6.0.7/bin/sidekiq:27:in `<top (required)>'
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/bin/sidekiq:23:in `load'
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/bin/sidekiq:23:in `<top (required)>'
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/cli/exec.rb:63:in `load'
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/cli/exec.rb:63:in `kernel_load'
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/cli/exec.rb:28:in `run'
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/cli.rb:476:in `exec'
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:399:in `dispatch'
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/cli.rb:30:in `dispatch'
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:476:in `start'
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/cli.rb:24:in `start'
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.1.2/exe/bundle:46:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:123:in `with_friendly_errors'
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.1.2/exe/bundle:34:in `<top (required)>'
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
```

I don't know if my sidekiq.pid file is missing or what am I doing wrong. Please help, Ive been trying to resolve this by almost two days!

Answer (score 0):

This error most likely occurs because of 6th version of Sidekiq doesn't support pidfile and daemonization mode.
The simplest way is to downgrade sidekiq through gemfile:
gem 'sidekiq', '< 6.0.0'.
https://www.mikeperham.com/2019/09/03/welcome-to-sidekiq-6.0/